# Is there a browser log or something like that?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, browser-tabs

I'm using Edge (Chromium) and want to figure out a tab is opened by which application/extension. The tab:

- has no history to go back/forward
- was not opened in a new browser window

I scanned [history - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history) but find nothing helpful. Could anyone give some suggestions?

Any solutions (third-party program/JavaScript API/...) are welcome.

Comment: Why are you searching documation on Firefox if you are using a Chromium based browser?

Comment: @Ramhound Well. MDN does have many useful documents on general browsers beyond Firefox. The most oblivious one would be the Browser compatibility table. I feel it's not specifically built for Firefox. (Though Firefox is often used as an example in their tutorials.)

Comment: Do you have any reason you can accomplish this with JavaScript?

Comment: @Ramhound If the `history` API provides some detailed attribute like `history.log`, then I can simply access it. To clarify, any solutions (other than JavaScritp) are welcome. JavaScript is only a trial.